# Выпадающее меню на CSS

Tags: html, css

Я уже третий день бьюсь на проблемой, верстаю в CSS. Когда дохожу до меню, у меня вечно оно разъезжается.

CSS:

```
ul.nav a,
ul.nav span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration:none; 
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    text-align:center; 
    font-weight:bold;  
    font-size:15px;  
}
ul.nav, 
ul.nav li, 
ul.nav ul 
{
    list-style:none;  
    margin:0;   
}
ul.nav 
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    float:right; 
    width:132px;

    display:inline;
}
ul.nav li {
    line-height: 2em; 
    width:135px;
    background: url(img/active.jpg) no-repeat center;
    height:40px;
}
ul.nav li.hover,
ul.nav li:hover 
{
    position: relative;
    z-index:12;
    cursor: default;
}
ul.nav ul 
{
    visibility: hidden; 
    position: absolute;  
    z-index: 11;
}
ul.nav ul li 
{
    background: center url(img/back.jpg) no-repeat; margin-left: -1px;
    float: left; 
}
ul.nav li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
} 
ul.nav li:hover 
{
    background: url(img/back2.jpg) no-repeat; margin-left:1px;
}
[href*="first"] {
    background:url(img/back.jpg) no-repeat center; margin-left:-2px;
}
[href*="last"]:hover {
    background:url(img/bottom.jpg) no-repeat  center; margin-left: -1px
}
[href*="last"] {
    background:url(img/active.jpg) no-repeat center; margin-left: 2px; height:40px
}
```

Дайте, пожалуйста, источники по работающим выпадающим меню на CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глядите: [урок по созданию выпадающего меню на CSS](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=941).

Там и демки и код есть, всё подробно разжёвано.

Ссылка не пашет, а ссылается.) Рабочая она, исправил уже.

Comment: СсылКо Не Пашед =( вот это вот выходит http://hashcode.ru/questions/17186/ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=941